# Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $V \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$,

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $V \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$, Prove that there exists a matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$, such that $U = WV$ if and only if $\ker(V)$ is a subspace of $\ker(U).$

i don't know how to prove the opposite direction. i.e.
if $\ker(V)$ is a subspace of $\ker(U).$, there exists a matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$, such that $U = WV$

Comment: Well, $UV$ is always well defined... so, such a $W$ always exist.

Comment: The dimensions do not (always) match at the moment.

Comment: I think the problem states $U = WV$ instead of $W = UV$. Am I right? Also, I think 
\begin{align}
\ker(U) &= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} : Ux = 0_m\}, \textrm{ and} \\
\ker(V) &= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} : Vx = 0_k\}.
\end{align}

Comment: yes, i have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a basis for Ker $V$, $(v_1,...,v_r)$ and extend this to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, $B = (v_1,...,v_r,v_{r+1},...,v_n)$.

Take a basis for Im $V$, $(V(v_{r+1}),...,V(v_n))$, and extend this to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Now define $W$ on this basis for $\mathbb{R}^k$ by

$W(V(v_i)) = U(v_i), \forall i \in \{r+1,...,n\}$

and define $W$ to be $0$ for the other basis elements.

Now it's not hard to prove that $U$ and $WV$ agree on the basis $B$, so $U = WV$.

---

Here is a bit more explanation. To define a linear transformation, we need only define it on some basis of its domain. In the case of $W$, this is $\mathbb{R}^k$. Take some basis $D = \{d_1,...,d_k\}$, and define

$W(d_i) = d_i'$

Then $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^k$, we have

$W(v) = W(\sum_{i=1}^k c_i d_i) = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i W(d_i) = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i d_i'$

So once we have defined $W$ on any basis we have completely determined it.

Also, the above shows if two transformations agree on a basis, then they must be equal.

Now let's take a look at $B$ and consider whether $U$ and $WV$ agree on this basis.

For $1 \le i \le r$, we have know $v_i \in $ Ker $V$ since we defined $B$ that way. Also since Ker $V \subseteq$ Ker $U$, $v_i \in $ Ker $U$, therefore

$U(v_i) = 0 = WV(v_i), \forall i \in \{1,...,r\} $

The way we defined $W$ above says that

$U(v_i) = WV(v_i), \forall i \in \{r+1,...,n\} $

So $U$ and $VW$ agree on the basis $B$ and we are done. Notice that when we defined $W$ on a basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$, the only elements of the basis that mattered were $(V(v_{r+1}),...,V(v_n))$. The other elements could have been defined to be anything, since they are not in the image of $V$. So there are many valid ways to construct a $W$.

Comment: still not get it. Why define W to be 0 for the other basis elements

Comment: And in this case, i don't know how to use the condition: ker(B) is a subspace of ker(A)

Comment: @apppleee I edited in a longer answer that provides a lot of detail.

Comment: got it. Thank you so much